ThreeJs model on website loads wrong in VueJs website, is temporaliy fixed on reload
I try to program a website [it is my first solo web project], and I am using NX for a solo-repo VueJs website with a ThreeJs model displayed on the Homepage. When I load the page the scale of the model seems too small. Switching to another subside or updating the layout seems to fixes the problem.
Here is my code of the HomeView.vue
<template>
  <main>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="splash-screen">
        <Hyperdrive></Hyperdrive>
        <Counter />
      </div>
      <div class="feed-container">
        <FeedItem
          v-for="(feed, index) in feeds"
          :key="index"
          :feed="feed"
          :index="index"
          :is-expanded="isExpanded[index]"
          @toggle-expand="toggleExpand(index)"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <a
          class="insta-button"
          href="https://www.instagram.com/sund.space/"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >Mehr Neuigkeiten</a
        >
      </div>
      <div class="rocket-element">
        <Rocket />
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Counter from '../components/CounterComponent.vue';
import feedData from '../../../src/assets/json/feed.json';
import FeedItem from '../components/FeedItemComponent.vue';
import Rocket from '../components/RocketComponent.vue';
import Hyperdrive from '../components/HyperdriveComponent.vue';

const feeds = ref(feedData);
const isExpanded = ref(new Array(feeds.value.length).fill(false));

const getImagePath = (imageName: string) => {
  return new URL(`../../../src/assets/pics/${imageName}`, import.meta.url).href;
};

const toggleExpand = (index: number) => {
  isExpanded.value[index] = !isExpanded.value[index];
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto; 
  gap: 16px; 
}

.splash-screen {
  grid-column: span 3;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.feed-container {
  grid-column: span 2; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px; 
}

.footer {
  grid-column: span 3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.rocket-element {
  grid-column: 3; 
  grid-row: 2 / span 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 25vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 20px; 
}

.insta-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.insta-button:hover {
  background-color: #fddb3a;
}
</style>

And here is my code of RocketComponent:
<template>
  <div ref="rocketContainer"></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';

// Importiere die .obj-Datei
import rocketObjUrl from '../../../src/assets/models/brand_new_rocket.obj';

const rocketContainer = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  // Define the perspective camera
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75, // Field of view (in degrees)
    rocketContainer.value!.clientWidth / rocketContainer.value!.clientHeight, // Aspect ratio
    0.1, // Near clipping plane
    1000 // Far clipping plane
  );

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(
    rocketContainer.value!.clientWidth,
    rocketContainer.value!.clientHeight
  );
  rocketContainer.value!.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  const loader = new OBJLoader();

  loader.load(
    rocketObjUrl,
    (object) => {
      object.scale.set(1, 1, 1); // Adjust scaling as needed
      scene.add(object);

      // Animation function to rotate the model around the z-axis
      const animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        object.rotation.y += 0.01; // Rotate around the z-axis
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      animate();
    },
    (xhr) => {
      console.log(`${(xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100}% loaded`);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('An error happened:', error);
    }
  );

  // Set the camera position and view
  camera.position.z = 200; // Move camera back to see the model
  camera.position.y = 0; // Adjust the vertical position to get a better view
  camera.position.x = 0;   // Center camera horizontally

  // Adjust the camera to look at the center of the model
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  // Handle window resizing
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = rocketContainer.value!.clientWidth / rocketContainer.value!.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(
      rocketContainer.value!.clientWidth,
      rocketContainer.value!.clientHeight
    );
  });
});
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

My first thought was that it was cache related so I cleared my browser cache and reset NX with nx reset. Both didn't work. Then I thought the RocketComponent was being loaded before the the Feed is being loaded and therefor the height of the whole website is being wrong when used by the RocketComponent, so I added defineEmit and FeedItemComponent emits a value to continue loading the 3d-model. But that didn't work neither.

Not sure why you even use a mono-repo for such a thing, just drop it. Also, if you're starting I might recommend trying to solve it in vanilla JS first (not using Vue or anything, especially if new to it). "another subside", client-side route navigation you mean here? The code itself doesn't scream anything specific, maybe use some devtools to check if it's a CSS problem or maybe a DOM issue where you could use nextTick but again, probably better to just strip a few abstractions at this level.

The model may already be small by default, try scaling it up. Also try to reduce the camera distance - the further away, the smaller the object.
camera.position.z = 20; Try put your OBJ here to check how looks like by default.
